# Location-based range search

Tags: drupal, search, drupal-6

I am trying to implement location-based range search using Drupal location and Gmap modules. Ideally I would like to have a form where the user can type in either zip/postal code or specific name - e.g. London + specify a range within which he would like to search. Currently I have a working searching functionality that returns map markers taking into account a numer of exposed filters. I am not sure however how to approach range search functionality. Has anyone any experience with this kind of functionality in Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once build a location based search for one of my projects, using the location module to stock geographic information in nodes and gmap to find the coordinates of the requested location. Then I manipulated or overrode (I don't recall exactly) the search and altered the sql query in a way that each node had a distance value added so that I could filter for nodes that are too far away from the requested location. Works like a charm, but I couldn't find any other way than coding it on my own.